# Unity GameObject is composed of components or is a collection of components?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it known if in Unity the GameObject is composed of components or they are just collections? I mean which one of these is done in Unity:

```
class GameObject
{
    TransformComponent   transformComponent;
    RenderingComonent    renderigComponent;
    ......
}


class GameObject
{
  List<Component>  allTypesOfcomponents;
}
```

Comment: The latter might make sense.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that Unity uses a lot of reflection internally - it may actually be that it uses the former approach and emits some IL for faster access. I know that you don't need to implement particular interfaces or inherit from any base class to create game objects, you can just do it all via convention. Check out this article - reflection is relatively slow, but with the correct approach member access via emitted IL can be as fast if not as fast as your precompiled code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18450/HyperDescriptor-Accelerated-dynamic-property-acces

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it matters in terms of how is it done internally; Unity developers could've easily switch from one option to the other, while maintaing exactly the same interface.

However, I think that it's some kind of a dictionary-based data structure (dictionary of lists, may be?), because iterating through a list to find a Component of particular type would be a completely unnecessary performance setback.